# MySQL: start group by after a value is reached

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying group by the column 'new_treads' at the value where 'response' first equals 1.

```
id   |treads    |response
------------------
1    | 1        | 0        
2    | 1        | 1
3    | 2        | 0    
4    | 2        | 0
5    | 2        | 1
6    | 2        | 1
7    | 2        | 1
...  | ...      | ...
15   | 9        | 0     
16   | 9        | 1    
17   | 9        | 0  
18   | 9        | 1 
19   | 10       | 0
```

Currently I can use:

```
SELECT 
thread,
count(response),
sum(response)
FROM messages
GROUP BY thread
```

To get:

```
treads    |count(response) | sum(response)
------------------------------------------
 1        | 2              | 1
 2        | 5              | 3
 9        | 4              | 2 
 10       | 1              | 0
```

But what I want to do is to start the group by, or count(response), where 'response' = 1. Giving:

```
treads    |count(response) | sum(response)
------------------------------------------
 1        | 1              | 1
 2        | 3              | 3
 9        | 3              | 2 
 10       | 0              | 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: does your messages table have a primary key? can you post the full definition of `messages` table?

Comment: it does. sorry about that. one second

Comment: Thanks. that made it a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is messy, sorry.

```
select treads, if(sum(response) >= 1, count(response), 0) count, sum(response) sum
  from messages
    where id not in (
     select m.id 
       from messages m 
       where id < 
        (select min(id) id 
          from messages 
          where response = 1 
            and treads = m.treads
         group by treads)
    )
    group by treads;
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fffd0/14

By way of explanation the first subquery gets all message ids where the id is less than the id of the first row for that tread where `response = 1` - this value comes from the innermost subquery, and this gives us an exclusion list to filter out the results of the outermost query.

We use the `if` statement inside the `count` to handle the case where the only record for a tread has `response = 0`, as you want it included in the results, but not counted.

Comment: ugh just noticed it returns the wrong value for a row where there is no `response = 1`. fixing (and fixed)

Comment: sorry for the late response. The query works but it takes about 15 secs for 500 rows of data. I have +100,000 rows. Is there a way to make this faster? Maybe to save the inner query in memory?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the explain plan for that query, as well as all the indexes from the tables?

Comment: a composite index on (treads, response) should help. If it doesn't, you can create a temporary table for the inner query